# Displaying DIVs side by side

Tags: html, css

I want to display it like this:

.
[image]

However the container wont center / cover the entire screen for the other columns to be side by side (I left out the left/right column in css, because I'm trying to find out how to make it work + the container just defaults to the top left of the screen.) Also how do I get them side by side like the layout, inside the entire screen container?

```css
#container {
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.title {
  color: #eee;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="leftColumn">
    <div class="center">
      <h1 class="title">requiem.moe</h1>
      <div id="center_wrap">
        <div id="yt">
          <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCWCLrljiADMzumB21isaMbg" target="_blank">> youtube <</a>
        </div>
        <div id="steam">
          <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/SevensRequiem/" target="_blank">> steam <</a>
        </div>
        <div id="hub">
          <a href="./t1">> old theme+hub <</a>
        </div>
        <div id="sharex">
          <a href="#">> New ShareX Server <</a>
        </div>
        <div id="tracks">
          <a href="#">tracklist N/A</a>
        </div>
        <div id="user">
          <a href="#">user system N/A</a>
        </div>
        <div id="aura">
          <a href="#">aura sys TBA</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="rightColumn">
        test
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Proper code formatting is crucial for a sane workflow. A good editor would've made obvious all the extra angle brackets in your markup. Please edit the post and the snippet therein to remove those and demonstrate your problem.

Comment: See [ask] and take the [tour] to learn how to use this site.

Comment: Can you attach a picture of what you see (from your CSS)?

Answer (score 3):

1. You put the `rightColumn` inside the `leftColumn`.
2. I recommend you using [FlexBox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). This is modern and most wanted.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid black
}

.container #leftColumn {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.container #rightColumn {
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="leftColumn">
    <div class="center">
      <h1 class="title">requiem.moe</h1>
      <div id="center_wrap">
        <div id="yt">
          <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCWCLrljiADMzumB21isaMbg" target="_blank">> youtube <</a>
        </div>
        <div id="steam">
          <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/SevensRequiem/" target="_blank">> steam <</a>
        </div>
        <div id="hub">
          <a href="./t1">> old theme+hub <</a>
        </div>
        <div id="sharex">
          <a href="#">> New ShareX Server <</a>
        </div>
        <div id="tracks">
          <a href="#">tracklist N/A</a>
        </div>
        <div id="user">
          <a href="#">user system N/A</a>
        </div>
        <div id="aura">
          <a href="#">aura sys TBA</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="rightColumn">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I recommended CSS Grid positioning in my answer, but the Flexbox suggestion in Amirreza's answer is also great for this type of layout. I just find CSS Grids more approachable to the way I think.

Comment: @LeeMcAlilly I agree with you. Flexbox is more common among developers. I think the future of responsive design is css grid.

Comment: @LeeMcAlilly flex is fine here for a 2 col container, it could even wrap into a single column  without a mediaquerie. ;) idea https://jsfiddle.net/akberojn/

Answer (score 0):

assign `display:flex; flex-direction: row;` to your container class. they will cause the left column and right column display in a row.

Comment: The direction of the *display flex* is row by default.

Comment: yes, you are right, it is just a habit of writing

Comment: You should set a snippet to demonstrate your answer, it will give a better value to your answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Don't position your container at all. You even don't need your container. The body element of your html could be the container, but if you do want a container, you could add something like `margin: auto` (this will center anything relative to its parent element) and `height: 100%` with `width: 100%`.

Then, your left column could be something like `display: block` with `width: 30%` and your right column `display: block` with `width 70%`.

I would consider using a CSS grid layout for this though.

One thing you might find helpful is starting with something like [TailwindCSS](https://tailwindcss.com) classes instead of writing your own CSS. It's a good way to learn the underlying CSS as well. For instance, [here are the docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/height) for `height: 100%`.

You can get started with Tailwind by simply including a link to their CND version of the Tailwind stylesheet in the head of your HTML document:

`<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Use that as your "stylesheet reset" and start playing around with Tailwind layout properties and I think you'll have a better entry point into learning more complex CSS layout.

Answer (score -1):

here is how to split to 2 parts:

```css
.split {top:0; height:100%; position:absolute;}
.left {width:20%; left:0; background-color:purple;}
.right {width:80%; right:0; background-color:green;}
```

```html
<div class="split left">
  <p>something</p>
 </div>
 <div class="split right">
  <p>something</p>
 </div>
```

To split, you need to write 20% for the left part, and 80% to the right part (as you can see in the CSS).

both of the `div`s need to have full height (as you can see in the CSS).

Comment: Nowdays , flex or grid are perfect, before there was **display:** table; and before the faux-column method with float and a background to mimic the column all the way down. position:fixed or absolute are really the last advise to give a beginner, it seems easy but fails so easily because the web is nothing alike a print media :)

Comment: You are right. They work very well. But I thought it would be a nice tool to use the easy and simple `width`, `height`, and `display: absolute` properties

Comment: You should add sort of a disclaimer or warning  introducing the absolute positionning in your answer, it would avoid downvotes ;)